# Integer determinism

Tags: c++, c, cpu, cpu-architecture

I just want to ask, are integers deterministic? I know they're supposed to be, but are they the same on all platforms?

I did a search on Google for it, but the only thing it returned was how to put two numbers together, and deep research into the subject of determinism.

The reason why I ask is because I'm planning on developing a small demo that features a lock-step network model. There will be a couple of blocks on the screen that will be movable via commands, and was thinking of giving all the blocks integer values.

This also led me to think about general RTS games that always have to struggle with desync with floating point numbers (It's not the only reason why they desync, but is still a major factor in desyncs). Why don't these games just use 64-bit integers for storing all unit positions, etc. I think 64-bits with its capacity to store gazilion different values will be more than enough to handle unit positions, etc.

Comment: Almost everything in the computer is deterministic in some way.  About the only exceptions are time related issues (and the results of reading `/dev/random`, if your system has it).

Comment: *"I just want to ask, are integers deterministic?"* - I think we have a problem of terminology here.  There is nothing like the limitations on floating point precision in regards to integers, no.

Comment: Deterministic ? in what way ? curious ? you want unique IDs (non repeatable) for your objects ?

Comment: @EdS I assume he means well-defined and with reproducible behavior across runs/platforms

Comment: Yes that's it, I want to send the user commands from one process to all other peer connected process and have them execute the exact same commands. So basically there will be a move command that will be send when a key is pressed. On the local machine this moves the block (which stores it's position in an integer) and all other peers follow the exact same steps.

Answer (score 1):

With only a few rare exceptions (e.g, timings on memory access, and explicitly random operations like [`RDRAND`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand)), all operations on a CPU are deterministic, including both integer and floating-point operations.

Desyncs in networked games tend to be the result of errors in game logic, not architectural issues.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent. The results of arithmetic operations will always be the same, as long as none of the operations overflow. The result of a signed integer overflowing is undefined. Compiler optimizations could result in different results even within the same invocation of the program. The result of unsigned overflow is well-defined; the results will always be the same as long as the two platforms have the same value for UINT_MAX. You also cannot rely on the actual binary representation that the platform uses. You will have to use some form of serialization if you want to pass integers between different machines.

Comment: +1 for the comment about binary rep (i.e. little vs big endian) and serialization.

Answer (score 1):

There are some important cases of undefined behavior; for example, if your expression generates an out-of-bounds signed integer value, even as an intermediate step, then literally anything can happen. (And "out-of-bounds" depends somewhat on the system; `int`, for example, is not guaranteed to be exactly 32 bits.) There are also some cases of implementation-defined behavior; for example, right-shift of an negative signed integer value is implementation-defined, meaning that the compiler can decide how it wants to handle it, and must document that decision.

And of course, in the event of multithreading, almost all bets are off unless you take care to handle synchronization properly.

But if you avoid those cases, then — there are no platforms on which `2+2` will be something other than `4`.

Comment: That's good news, I was only going to use plus and minus operators to change the integer values. Also, I don't believe there will be real pressing issues of these value's overflowing, because I plan to use 64-bit integers